# Is there any easy way to assign JSON data to svg element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, svg

I am new to SVG, and trying to create a simple graph using it.
But I don't know how assign JSON data to draw a rectangle in SVG dynamically using 'for loop'.Help me to get 1 loop and assigning each value to draw rectangle that I want to append to SVG element.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var data = [  
{   
    "srno" : 1 ,
    "status" : "production" , 
    "duration" : 30,
    "color" : "#00ff00",
},
{
    "srno" : 2 ,
    "status" : "idle" , 
    "duration" : 5 ,
    "color" : "#ff0000"}];
  //Make an SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", 720)
.attr("height", 50);
 //Draw the Rectangle
 var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect")
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("width", machines [1].duration)
.attr("height", 50)
.attr("fill","green");//Here I want the color from JSON object
//And I want duration to be the width property, 
//Status be the tooltip , which is not working 
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code of what you have tried so far? Is this homework assignment?

Comment: Could you please share some code, as it will tell us exactly where you are stucked. It will also save effort for other people as they don't have to start from scratch. Also , unreleveant answers will be avoided

Comment: Here is the code I am practising on. Sorry for inconvenience @Both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good **article** where you can learn on how to do that:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/05/animated-svg-icons-with-snap-svg/

You can download the source files, within the "js" directory you will find a json file using svg data.

You might consider use **Snap.svg**, could help you a lot:

http://snapsvg.io/

Hope it helps you!

Comment: No problem i'm here to help!

Comment: Can you please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046644/can-we-create-div-on-mousehover-of-svg-element-to-have-multi-line-tooltip-using @Rodrigo, i need to have tooltip that too multilines?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working result..

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var data = [  
{   
"srno" : 1 ,
"status" : "production" , 
"duration" : 30,
"color" : "#00ff00",
},
{
"srno" : 2 ,
"status" : "idle" , 
"duration" : 5 ,
"color" : "#ff0000"}
];
for ( var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'rect');
var width = data [i].duration ;
rect.setAttribute('x',20);
rect.setAttribute('y',10);
rect.setAttribute('width',data[i].duration);
rect.setAttribute('height',50);
rect.setAttribute('fill',data[i].color);
}};
</script>
```