# can we create div on mousehover of svg element to have multi line tooltip using simple javascript, DOM and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

As I am new to svg, I have a new problem in it, I am trying to create a simple graph where I need to have multiline tooltip.
Please suggest how to add tooltip (JSON object) to javascript, to display it as a multiline tooltip?
And can we use div, give properties to div and use it as a tooltip, like making it visible or invisible on mouse hover event?

```
    window.onload = function(){
    var data = [  
    {   
        "srno" : 1 ,
        "start_time":0,
        "status" : "Breakdown" , 
        "duration" : 100,
        "color" : "#CC0000",
        "tooltip"   :   "Show up: 12:30
                    status:Break down
                    Duration:100"           
    },
    {
        "srno" : 2 ,
        "status" : "Mold-Change" , 
        "duration" :70 ,
        "color" : "#FF8000",
        "start_time":100 ,
        "tooltip"   :   "Show up: 2:30
                    status:Break down
                    Duration:100"   
    }
    ] ;
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;


for ( var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){

var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'rect');


        var width = data [i].duration ;
        rect.setAttribute('x',data [i].start_time);
        rect.setAttribute('y',0);
        rect.setAttribute('width',data[i].duration);
        rect.setAttribute('height',50);
        rect.setAttribute('fill',data[i].color);

        var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
        text.setAttribute('x', data [i].start_time+2 );
        text.setAttribute('y', '25');
        text.setAttribute('fill', '#fff');
        text.textContent = data[i].status;

        var textWrapper = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
        var tips = document.createElement("P");
        tips.innerHTML = data[i].tooltip;

        document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(rect);
        document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(text); 

        rect.appendChild(textWrapper);
        }
   };
```

With single line It works, please suggest about multilines? I just wanted the way to create multiline using Json or to create div which will contain information same as tooltip?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an SVG "tooltip"-like box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102457/how-to-create-an-svg-tooltip-like-box)

Comment: how it will go with JSON and SVG? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a foreignObject instead of a text element and then put your content inside it (I wrapped it with a p, but it could be any HTML). After that, everything becomes plain HTML.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var data = [
        {
            "srno": 1,
            "start_time": 0,
            "status": "Breakdown",
            "duration": 100,
            "color": "#CC0000",
            "tooltip": "Show up: 12:30 <br />status:Break down <br />Duration:100"//JSON object to show as tooltip in multilines
        },
        {
            "srno": 2,
            "status": "Mold-Change",
            "duration": 70,
            "color": "#FF8000",
            "start_time": 100,
            "tooltip": "Show up: 2:30 <br />status:Mold-Change <br />Duration:70"//JSON object to show as tooltip in multilines
        }
    ];
    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;


    for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {

        var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect');


        var width = data[i].duration;
        rect.setAttribute('x', data[i].start_time);
        rect.setAttribute('y', 0);
        rect.setAttribute('width', data[i].duration);
        rect.setAttribute('height', 50);
        rect.setAttribute('fill', data[i].color);

        var textWrapper = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
        textWrapper.setAttribute('x', data[i].start_time + 2);
        textWrapper.setAttribute('y', '25');
        textWrapper.setAttribute('fill', '#fff');
        textWrapper.setAttribute('width', data[i].duration);
        textWrapper.setAttribute('height', 50);

        var text = document.createElement("P");
        text.innerHTML = data[i].tooltip;
        textWrapper.appendChild(text);

        var title = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'title');
        title.textContent = data[i].title;

        document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(rect);
        document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(textWrapper);

        rect.appendChild(title);
    }
};
```

Other alternatives in http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#Introduction (3rd paragraph) and reason for this in http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextLayoutIntroduction (2nd paragraph)

**Edit**

For a tooltip, try this (on Chrome)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SO</title>
    <style>
        p {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var data = [
                {
                    "srno": 1,
                    "start_time": 0,
                    "status": "Breakdown",
                    "duration": 100,
                    "color": "#CC0000",
                    "tooltip": "Show up: 12:30 \nstatus:Break down \nDuration:100"//JSON object to show as tooltip in multilines
                },
                {
                    "srno": 2,
                    "status": "Mold-Change",
                    "duration": 70,
                    "color": "#FF8000",
                    "start_time": 100,
                    "tooltip": "Show up: 2:30 \nstatus:Mold-Change \nDuration:70"//JSON object to show as tooltip in multilines
                }
            ];
            var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
            var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;


            for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {

                var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect');


                var width = data[i].duration;
                rect.setAttribute('x', data[i].start_time);
                rect.setAttribute('y', 0);
                rect.setAttribute('width', data[i].duration);
                rect.setAttribute('height', 50);
                rect.setAttribute('fill', data[i].color);

                var textWrapper = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
                textWrapper.setAttribute('x', data[i].start_time);
                textWrapper.setAttribute('y', '0');
                textWrapper.setAttribute('width', data[i].duration);
                textWrapper.setAttribute('height', 50);

                var text = document.createElement("P");
                text.setAttribute('title', data[i].tooltip);
                text.style.height = "50px";
                textWrapper.appendChild(text);

                var title = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'title');
                title.textContent = data[i].title;

                document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(rect);
                document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(textWrapper);

                rect.appendChild(title);
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="mySVG">
    </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Does it mean "p" element will work as tooltip? @potatopeelings

Comment: If you are asking if it will show the content (i.e. just like a text SVG element did), yes it will. If you are asking if it will go off when you mouseout, no it won't. However you can modify the code a bit to make that happen - replace the <br/> by \n, instead of innerHTML, setAttribute(title, ...) and then size the p (with css or javascript) to fill the textWrapper.

Comment: silly of me! made a mistake.@potatopeelings. I changed the code, Is it same that should work? If yes, It is still not working

Comment: I dont know why the effects like being transparent on rectangle on mouse over doesnot work as well as the speed of tooltip showing up is too slow? Can we add something to raise speed and look fab? @potatopeelings

Comment: The speed is not something that can be controlled. It's driven by the browser. All in all, if you are looking to control styling and all, it would be better to go for a javascript library than trying to do it from scratch. something like http://raphaeljs.com/ perhaps, though I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77069/discussion-between-sia-and-potatopeelings).